# Delete entity with all childs connected

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have been trying to remove single **Item** from database properly, to satisfy FK restrictions.

I got **Item** entity (for using in EF) which get referred by multiple others

```cs
public class Item
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    ...
    public FoodItem FoodItem { get; set; }
    public LocalItem LocalItem { get; set; }
    public ItemToCategory ItemToCategory { get; set; }
}
```

Where *Id* is PK for **Item** and FK for other entities.

I see two possible approaches to delete entity and childs:

1. Get connected entity through LINQ query;
2. Give *CascadeDelete* constraint to my **Item**.

**First**:

As I found this far, my query must be like

```cs
Item basicItem = await db.Items.Include(b => b.LocalItem)
                            .Include(b => b.FoodItem)
                            .Include(b => b.ItemToCategory)
                            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == productId);

db.Items.Remove(basicItem);
await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

But I get `Source sequence contains more than one element` error and have no idea why.

**Second**:

It's still a way, but I want to suspend it for a while. Cause I see it, like less safe approach.

So, returning back to topic: How can I get my entity deleted with all *childs* connected?

Comment: How about FirstOrDefault() instead of SingleOrDefault() ?

Comment: Note that it won’t cascade delete the included relationships though… Method 2 is definitely the easiest if you don’t wan’t to iterate through all the related entries !

Comment: FirstOrDefault() just seems unobvious, why it returns sequence instead of single entity. And maybe you right about method 2

Comment: Are you sure that you have only one record for the product id you are providing ? because SingleOrDefaultAsync expects  that there is only one item in the record otherwise it throws an error 

Aslo cascade delete is not a recommended option as it will cause performance issue as you database grows bigger

Comment: I tried FirstOfDeafult() anyway, and new error explicitly stated that I need to add cascade delete behavior - so I did.

Comment: Should I then create an answer ? Did it solve your problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, I choose to set cascade delete constraint on connected entites